# How do I use jQuery UI's Highlight and Error widgets?

Tags: jquery-ui

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) has some nice convenient CSS styles for alerting and highlighting. I can see it at [the themeroller site](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) -- look on the right hand side. Is there a Javascript interface to these styles? Do we use hard-coded CSS? Where is this documented?

Is there method list, a cheatsheat, or anything other than the interactive docs on jQuery UI?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Apply the appropriate CSS classes for the desired interaction cue from the [UI/Theming/API](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API#Interaction_Cues) page: **.ui-state-highlight** for highlight and **.ui-state-error** for error. You can do it statically or use `.addClass('ui-state-highlight')` or `.addClass('ui-state-error')` to do it dynamically.

Comment: Your answer is good enough to be chosen, I believe this to be right -- but check out this link i got from irc thanks to `ajpiano` -- never saw it before today http://wiki.jqueryui.com/jQuery-UI-CSS-Framework

Comment: Sweet! I will Instapaper that.

Answer (score 4):

I have adapted a short jQuery function to convert a given set of divs (containing text) into error/highlight elements.

You can see it in action on [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/774wH/).

Here is the javascript:

```
//function to create error and alert dialogs
function errorHighlight(e, type, icon) {
    if (!icon) {
        if (type === 'highlight') {
            icon = 'ui-icon-info';
        } else {
            icon = 'ui-icon-alert';
        }
    }
    return e.each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('ui-widget');
        var alertHtml = '<div class="ui-state-' + type + ' ui-corner-all" style="padding:0 .7em;">';
        alertHtml += '<p>';
        alertHtml += '<span class="ui-icon ' + icon + '" style="float:left;margin-right: .3em;"></span>';
        alertHtml += $(this).text();
        alertHtml += '</p>';
        alertHtml += '</div>';

        $(this).html(alertHtml);
    });
}

//error dialog
(function($) {
    $.fn.error = function() {
        errorHighlight(this, 'error');
    };
})(jQuery);

//highlight (alert) dialog
(function($) {
    $.fn.highlight = function() {
        errorHighlight(this, 'highlight');
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Indeed, it should be by default in jQuery UI as a replacement for alert()

Answer (score 2):

They are just CSS styles.  You can apply them on the backend, or apply them using .addClass().

Comment: Nice suggestion... What's the class name?

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to share one more solution. It's based on custom widgets and allows to add a title and customizable icon. Try [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7CHB/) or look below:

```
$.widget('custom.noteBox', {
options: {
    icon: true,
    state: 'highlight'
},
_create: function () {
    var icon, note = $('<p>').html(this.element.html());
    if (this.options.icon === true) {
        switch (this.options.state) {
            case 'highlight':
                icon = 'info';
                break;
            case 'error':
                icon = 'alert';
                break;
            default:
                icon = false;
        }
    } else {
        icon = this.options.icon;
    }
    if (icon) note.prepend($('<span>')
        .addClass('ui-icon ui-icon-' + icon)
        .css({
        'float': 'left',
        'margin-right': '.3em'
    }));
    var title = this.element.attr('title');
    if (title) note.prepend($('<strong>').text(title + ' '));
    this.element.addClass('ui-widget')
        .replaceWith($('<div>')
        .addClass('ui-state-' + this.options.state + ' ui-corner-all')
        .css({
        'margin-top': '20px',
        'padding': '0 .7em'
    })
        .append(note));
   }
});


$('.error').noteBox({
    state: 'error'
 });
$('.info').noteBox();
$('<div title="Note! ">I`m dynamically added #1</div>')
    .appendTo('body').noteBox({
    icon: 'folder-open'
 });
 $('<div title="Note! ">I`m dynamically added #2</div>')
    .appendTo('body').noteBox({
    state: 'error'
 });
 $('<div title="Note! ">I`m dynamically added #3</div>')
    .appendTo('body').noteBox({
    state: 'error',
    icon: 'trash'
 });
```

Comment: That is very clever and it illustrated well a creative solution to what the op have asked!