# Apply jQuery "highlight" theme styles using javascript?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-theme

I'm using [jQuery UI Themes](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) with one of my web applications.

If I want to apply button styling, I add the following jquery code:

```
$(".button").button();
```

Where `.button` is a class on the button I wish to style with jquery themes.

[image]

---

How can I do a similar thing to apply theme styles to an element which I want to style as a "highlight"?

[image]

I tried `.highlight();`, but this hasn't worked.

**Note:** I'm aware that I can manually add the CSS classes to my elements, but I wish to apply this with jQuery as this would save me adding the `span` element which displays the icon.

Therefore I want to be able to have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="highlight">
   <strong>Warning!</strong> Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

Which is then converted, using jQuery, into:

```
<div class="highlight ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all" style="margin-bottom:20px">
   <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>
   <strong>Warning!</strong> Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

---

Or, have I misunderstood what the use of the "Highlight" example is on the Theme roller page? I've assumed this is a warning box, considering its next to an error example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use jQuery UI's Highlight and Error widgets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168569/how-do-i-use-jquery-uis-highlight-and-error-widgets)

Comment: @Esailija That is showing how to add the css classes. See my note, I wish to have the `span` element automatically added.

Comment: So `$(".button").button().addClass('ui-state-highlight')` is not what you want?

Comment: @Esailija No the button was just an example of how styles are applied by calling `button()`.

Comment: You have rejected two "plugins" already, but there isn't anything built into jquery that will automagically do this for you. You either need to add the elements and classes appropriately, or let a plugin do that for you.

Comment: @KevinB On that note I've accepted the first plugin. I remember reading somewhere that you shouldn't manually add jquery ui classes, and that jquery ui functions would do this for you. It seems this is clearly not the case then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mTu2R/3/

```
$.fn.highlight = function() {
    return this.each(function() {

        var elem = $(this), p = $("<p>", {
            html: '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>' + 
                  elem.html()
        });

        elem.empty().addClass("ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all").append(p);

    });
};

$(".highlight").highlight();
```

Comment: Cheers for this, but I already knew making my own would be an option. I'm wondering if there is anything built in for this in the jQuery UI library? Just like there is for the `button` function?

Comment: @Curt according to the duplicate I linked, no.

Comment: Cheers I was thinking people were missing my point, but as one of the comments states it seems there is no built in way of doing this. Therefore I've accepted your answer and will use this in practice :) cheers again!

Answer (score 0):

Plugin keeps existing ID and classes

```
(function($){
$.fn.highlight=function(){
     return this.each(function(){                              
            var text=$(this).text();
            var id=this.id;
            var thisClass=$(this).attr('class');
            var $el=$('<div class="highlight ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all" style="margin-bottom:20px">\
                   <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>\
                   <strong>'+text+'</strong> Lorem Ipsum</p>\
                </div>').attr(id, id).addClass( thisClass);

             $(this).replaceWith($el);
        });

};
})(jQuery);

$(anyElement).highlight();
```

Comment: This hasn't answered my question

Comment: addClass( className)   I missed the function aspect of your example..apolgies, no other shortcuts

Comment: I class this as manually adding the classes. I'm after a way of jQuery determining the classes based on a function call. Just like `.button()` does.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I may be missing the point here, but you've said you want to do this "with jQuery", so:

```
$(".highlight").each(function() {
    var elm, p;

    elm = $(this);
    // Create the new paragraph and span
    p = $('<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span></p>');
    // Add the classes to the element
    elm.addClass("ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all");
    // Move the element's children into the paragraph
    p.append(elm.contents());
    // Append the paragraph
    elm.append(p);
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ifonat) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ifonat/edit)